# Github UI is messed up

Tags: github

I am having a weird issue and I'm not sure if this should go here or on another website. 
When I open a file on github I get this strange UI:

[image]

From there if I try and edit a file I just get a blank white page.

I am using chrome and tried using incognito but I got the same results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't reproduce that on the latest Chrome or Firefox for [`naguibihab/postman-tests`](https://github.com/naguibihab/postman-tests).

So in your case, a cache issue or an extra plugin might be the cause, but there is no issue on the GitHub side.

Comment: I'm on the latest chrome but it could be a plugin, I'll try disabling those and see what comes up